# Subquery select as filed

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I tried to make a subselect in a MySQL selct statement e.g. like the following one:

```
SELECT
  c.id AS id,
  c.name AS name,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM orders o WHERE o.user_id = c.id) AS order_count
FROM
  customers c
```

Any ideas why this does not work in MySQL?
Is it possible to do something like that in MySQL?
Tried it in Version 3.23.58 and 5.1.60.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you are getting ,when you execute the above (your) query ?

Answer (score 2):

You missed `,` after `name`, try this:

```
SELECT
  c.id AS id,
  c.name AS name,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM orders o WHERE o.user_id = c.id) AS order_count
FROM
  customers c
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid these sorts of errors (like missing commas), I like to write queries out like this...

```
    SELECT c.id 
         , c.name 
         , COALESCE(COUNT(o.user_id),0) order_count
      FROM customers c
      LEFT
      JOIN orders o
        ON o.user_id = c.id
     GROUP
        BY c.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  c.id AS id ,
  c.name AS name ,
 (SELECT count(*) 
   FROM orders o 
   WHERE o.user_id = c.id) AS order_count
FROM
 customers c
```

Use ',' after every column

Answer (score 0):

Another method using `joins`

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6a90/2)

Sample data:

```
ID  NAME
1   john
2   jack
3   kelly

ID  USERID
10  1
11  2
12  1
13  3
14  2
15  3
16  2
17  4
18  1
```

Query:

```
SELECT count(o.userid), c.id, c.name
FROM cusomter c
LEFT JOIN orders o
ON c.id = o.userid
GROUP BY c.id
;
```

You may add `case when` to represent null as a 0 if a customer doesen't have any orders. You choice.

Results:

```
COUNT(O.USERID)     ID  NAME
3                   1   john
3                   2   jack
2                   3   kelly
```

Comment: @Patrick I wrote this query having a thought on another method as well as **[performance on Joins vs Subquery in MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-subquery)**. Check this link out ;)